# Angular 2 boiler plate?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a simple Angular 2 boiler plate here

https://plnkr.co/edit/bT4mxVaUNnxfIm5t0zFQ?p=preview

Can anyone see why its not working

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name:string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular`
  }

}
```

Comment: I'd highly suggest using the Angular CLI to generate your application boilerplate. You can find it here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: @DeborahK, I don't use angular-cli for exploring, there's too much that you don't need

Comment: I use https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter as a boiler plate for my Angular4x projects and I'm happy with it so far.

Comment: I use the angular cli but I just need something simple in plunker to quickly test things

Comment: https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Ready-To-Use-Boilerplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you imported `environment` in the `src/main.ts`:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

and there's no `environments/environment` file in the plunker. Just add the following:

```
export const environment = { production: false };
```

to the `src/environments/environment.ts` and it will work.

[Here is](https://plnkr.co/edit/sSMIifIJG4vIsaonLUP3?p=preview) the working plunker.